# Array iteration with iself

Tags: javascript

I have an array of values like:

```
["34.44","55.22","15.32","21.67","98.76","14.57"]
```

and I want to iterate between themselves like

```
Calculate(34.44, 55.22);
Calculate(34.44, 15.32);
Calculate(34.44, 21.67);
Calculate(34.44, 98.76);
Calculate(34.44, 14.57);
Calculate(55.22, 15.32);
Calculate(55.22, 21.67);
Calculate(55.22, 98.76);
```

and so on...

what would be best way to iterate them in Javascript?
I was easily thinking having two arrays with same values and interate between first array and second array but could exists a better way for performance...

Thanks in advance to everyone!
Cheers,
Luigi

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: _"I want to iterate between themselves"_ - You mean that you want to take each combination of two values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for( var i=0; i<myarray.length; i++ ) {
    for( var j=i+1; j<myarray.length; j++ ) {
        Calculate( myarray[i], myarray[j] );
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have tried this like this:

`myarray = new Array("34.44","55.22","15.32","21.67","98.76","14.57");
for( var i=0; i<myarray.length; i++ ) {
    for( var j=i+1; j<myarray.length; j++ ) {
        document.write(i + " " + j);
        document.write("<br />");
    }
 }`
try pasting it and it is working. 
This answer by craiglm is correct. Please mark it as the correct answer. I did this so that I could see if the values are pairing right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) methods on the array.

```
var array = ["34.44", "55.22", "15.32", "21.67", "98.76", "14.57"];

array.forEach(function(numberLeft, indexLeft) {
    array.forEach(function(numberRight, indexRight) {
        // skip previous numbers and itself
        if (indexLeft >= indexRight)
            return;

        Calculate( numberLeft, numberRight );
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this do each combination twice?

Answer (score 0):

`Array.forEach` doesn't allow to do this kind of iteration, your best option is to just make two loops on the index:

```
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    for (var j=i+1; j<x.length; j++) {
        ... do whatever you need with x[i], x[j] ...
    }
}
```

if instead you need to process `x[a]`, `x[a]` pairs (i.e. the same element twice) and also both `x[a], x[b]` pair and `x[b], x[a]` pair then `forEach` can shorten the code (and probably will run faster).

```
x.forEach(function(x1){ x.forEach(function(x2){
    ... do whatever you weant with x1, x2 ...
})});
```

but note that `forEach` will iterate only over the elements that have been actually assigned, not in all the range `0..length-1`. For example after

```
x = [];
x[2] = 42;
```

the loop `x.forEach(...)` will not iterate over the undefined elements `x[0]` and  `x[1]`.